# .htaccess don't work after php upgrade

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I purchased yesterday a virtual private server with PHP version 5.3.3
Then i upgraded my php version to 5.4.22
Now the htaccess doesnt functional normally.. It doesn't do anything.
What i tried:
I did this in my httpd.conf

```
 <Directory />
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
 </Directory>
```

And it didn't work so i tried this in my .htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(inc|php|php3|php4|php5|php6|phtml|phps)$">
SetHandler x-httpd-php54
</FilesMatch>
```

And this doesn't work either.
If i create a page with `<?php phpinfo() ?>` and i check the loaded modules i see that mod_rewrite is loaded.

My .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|log|sh|inc|bak)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^d/(.*)$ delete.php?img=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^i/(.*)$ i.php?img=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^e/(.*)$ editor.php?img=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^u/$ /u/index.php?img=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ getimage.php?image=$1



RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpeg|png|bmp|jpg) http://(ip)/6j5o [NC,L]
ErrorDocument 400 http://(ip)/404.php
ErrorDocument 401 http://(ip)/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 http://(ip)/404.php
ErrorDocument 404 http://(ip)/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 http://(ip)/404.php
```

Any ideas? (My server is a Centos 6 64bit)

Comment: Have you upgraded apache also or just PHP?

Comment: i followed this tutorial: http://www.tecmint.com/install-apache-mysql-php-on-redhat-centos-fedora/ and there was a apache upgrade i think

Comment: I could be wrong, but shouldn't your Directory "tag" have the full directory path in it from the absolute root? such as `<Directory /var/www/>`

Comment: You should look in you `httpd.conf` for `mod_rewrite.so` and uncomment the line...

Comment: What type of Linux? (CentOS, Ubuntu, etc). Also, you shouldn't need to `SetHandler` if PHP is loaded properly. A normal add in httpd.conf looks like `AddHandler php5-script .php`

Comment: @Machavity if you readed the topic, i sayed "centos 6 64bit"

Comment: Apologies for missing that. Can you post the output of `rpm -qa php*`?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/kbtnpqr2 here!

Answer (score 1):

Your Apache config is at `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`. Make sure this line is not commented out

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Now, head over to `/etc/httpd/conf.d` and look at the config for your site (I hope you've made your own `sitename.conf` in here). You should have something like this (yours will probably differ a fair amount, this is from a server hosting one site)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydir
    ServerName my.domain.name
        ServerAlias my.domain.name

    ErrorLog logs/mydomain
    CustomLog logs/mydomain common

    <Directory "/var/www/html/mydir">
        Allow from all
        Options +FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Make sure you use full path names to your site's root directory.